# How to get date difference in minutes using Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, date-difference

Below query is my sql server query and I want it to convert it into hive query:

```
select DATEDIFF([minute], '19000101', '2013-01-01 10:10:10')
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use [`unix_timestamp`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) for dates after `1970`:

```
SELECT (unix_timestamp('2013-01-01 10:10:10') 
      - unix_timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00'))/60
```

1. Convert both dates to seconds from `1970-01-01`
2. Substract them
3. Divide by 60 to get minutes

**EDIT:**

Adding Minutes: `change date to unixtime -> add var * 60sec -> convert back to date`

```
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2013-01-01 10:10:10') + 10 * 60) AS result
```

**[db<>fiddle demo using MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cbcb050af086cbec621e7e2a7a9abed0)**

Comment: Also I would like to add that can we do same for adding mintues??